# Element Should Contain Text - for disabled field

Tags: selenium, appium, robotframework-ide

I am working on automation tests using `Appium` and `Robotframework`. The keyword `Element Should Contain Text` seems to return empty if the input field is disabled. How to verify a disabled input field has a given value?

```
<input type="text" id="myId" name="myName" disabled />
```

I get the following error:

```
Element 'myId' should have contained text 'myValue' but its text was ''.
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the properties of the field shown in UIAutomator?  Specifically, is there a property set for NAF?  (not accessible friendly).

Comment: Sorry. I don't have any idea of what you are talking about. Where can I get that from?

Comment: Whatever tool you are using to determine your xpath.  I'm using the UIAutomator that comes with Android Studio.  When you select an item from the screen capture, it displays all the available properties for that element: class, resource-id, text, etc.  There is a special case, and I don't recall if NAF is the property name or the value, but it means you cannot access the element.  It only appears if it applies, in other words you won't see the property unless the element has been specifically tagged by the developer as non-accessible.  This sometimes happens on password fields, for example.

Comment: Most likely, when the element is disabled the text is contained in some other element, probably nested inside of the element you're currently checking. There isn't really a way to help beyond guessing without seeing the actual document structure(ie. `html` for webapps) for the element you're not able to get the text from. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is correct and you are passing the correct id/classname. If this does not work please post the HTML code you are using. Adding some of the sample example which you can try out :-

If your tag is something like this below -

```
<input disabled="true" id='data'>
```

Your code should be -

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElements(By.id('my-id'));
webElement.getAttribute("disabled")
```

or

```
WebElement.getAttribute("id")
```

For this tag -

```
<input id="j_idt93:j_idt93" type="text" disabled="disabled" maxlength="2000" value="Pārtraukts">
```

To get the value attribute -

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt93:j_idt93")).getAttribute("value");
```

If this does not work you may have to use the javascript executor -

```
String value =  (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("Java script query  in here to return value","");
```

Your query should be -

```
return document.getElementById("j_idt93:j_idt93").getAttribute("value");
```

Let me know if this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Its true selenium returns empty if I assert text in disabled fields by using `Element or page contains text..`. However we can compare the text in field by using `Get Value` and then comparing the field value with the value you want to assert by `should be equal`.
In your case what you can do is,

```
${valueInField}      Get Value            myId

should be equal      ${valueInField}      ${myValue}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

```
*** Keywords ***
Should Not Be Empty
    [Arguments]                 ${locator}
    ${getValueOfTextField}=     Get Element Attribute       ${locator}     value
    Should Not Be Empty         ${getValueOfTextField}
```

I didn't get the value out, but I'm sure it's not empty.